# How to delete cloudwatch alarms that are attached to non-existent instances?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, amazon-cloudwatch

When I create new EC2 instances I use an ansible [dynamic inventory](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_dynamic_inventory.html#example-aws-ec2-external-inventory-script) to create new cloudwatch metrics alarms. So far so good:

```yaml
- name: set AWS CloudWatch alarms
  hosts: tag_env_production
  vars:
    alarm_slack: 'arn:aws:sns:123:metrics-alarms-slack'
  tasks:
    - name: "CPU > 70%"
      ec2_metric_alarm:
        state: present
        name: "{{ ec2_tag_Name }}-CPU"
        region: "{{ ec2_region }}"
        dimensions:
          InstanceId: '{{ ec2_id }}'
        namespace: "AWS/EC2"
        metric: CPUUtilization
        statistic: Average
        comparison: ">="
        threshold: 70.0
        unit: Percent
        period: 300
        evaluation_periods: 1
        description: Triggered when CPU utilization is more than 70% for 5 minutes
        alarm_actions: ['{{ alarm_slack }}']
      when: ec2_tag_group == 'lazyservers'
```

Executing as follows:

```
ansible-playbook -v ec2_alarms.yml -i inventories/ec2/ec2.py
```

After creating the new instances I drop the old ones (manually). The problem is that I'd need to delete the alarms for existing metrics attached to the old instances.

Am I missing something or there is no way how to do this via the dynamic inventory?

My current idea is to delete the metrics for instances that are in the "Terminating" state, but the downside is that if I run the playbook after those instances are terminated, they simply won't be visible.

Comment: why you create diferent alarms for each instance?

Comment: @RaulHugo: I've updated the question. The new servers always have new names assigned and the alarm names use those instance names. Can you please explain your approach a bit if it is still relevant?

Answer (score 1):

Before delete the instance, delete the alarm try with something like this:

```
- name: delete alarm
  ec2_metric_alarm:
    state: absent
    region: ap-southeast-2
    name: "cpu-low"
    metric: "CPUUtilization"
    namespace: "AWS/EC2"
    statistic: Average
    comparison: "<="
    threshold: 5.0
    period: 300
    evaluation_periods: 3
    unit: "Percent"
    description: "This will alarm when a bamboo slave's cpu usage average is lower than 5% for 15 minutes "
    dimensions: {'InstanceId':'{{ instance_id }}'}
    alarm_actions: ["action1","action2"]
```

Comment: Well, yes I could use this approach, but now I create new servers&alarms via the dynamic inventory but delete old servers and alarms manually so far. Problem with the dynamic inventories is that I cannot see the servers that have already been terminated - I've mentioned that I can delete those in "Terminating" state, but it is too late when the instances are already terminated.